# python smtp receipt confirmation DSN

Tags: python, email

I am dealing with sporadic non-delivery of emails sent using python2.7.6 from a linux cluster to internal email recipients whose addresses are known to be valid. Since the originating code used the deprecated syntax of `cat <file> | mailx -s <subject> <recipient>` to generate a cmd for submission as a `subprocess(cmd, shell=True)`, I have some working amended code-in-progress using smtp as below.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
def emailer(from_addr, to_addr, subj, email_body):
    if not os.path.isfile(email_body):
        msg = MIMEText(email_body)  
    else:
        with open(email_body, 'rb') as FHrb:
            msg = MIMEText(FHrb.read())
    msg['Subject']=subj
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost'); s.set_debuglevel(True)
    try:
        s.sendmail(from_addr,
               ','.join(to_addr) if isinstance(to_addr, list) else to_addr.split(','),
               msg.as_string())
    except Exception as e:
        print e

    s.quit()
```

When called this code returns to console the verbosity below (specific details masked by  to protect the innocent & reduce post size)

```
send: 'ehlo <localhost>.<localdomain>\r\n'
reply: '250-<localhost>.localdomain\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 10240000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: <localhost>.localdomain
PIPELINING
SIZE 10240000
VRFY
ETRN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN 
send: 'mail FROM:<SENDER> size=4178\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
send: 'rcpt TO:<me@my_email_address>\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Ok
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
data: (354, 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nSubject: subject supplied\r\n\r\n\r\n<CONTENT REMOVED>.\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7548F12004F\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7548F12004F
data: (250, '2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7548F12004F')
{}
```

The trailing empty {} indicates success. Which is confirmed by the maillogs:

```
Feb  1 11:02:06 <localhost> postfix/smtpd[19642]: 7548F12004F: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Feb  1 11:02:06 <localhost> postfix/cleanup[18681]: 7548F12004F: message-id=<20170201110206.7548F12004F@<localhost>.localdomain>
Feb  1 11:02:06 <localhost> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 7548F12004F: from=<ngsservice@<localhost>.localdomain>, size=4685, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  1 11:02:06 <localhost> postfix/smtp[19867]: 7548F12004F: to=me@my_email_address, relay=<our ip address>[<our ip address>]:25, delay=0.5, delays=0/0.01/0/0.48, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20170201110206.7548F12004F@<localhost>.localdomain> [InternalId=32804943] Queued mail for delivery)
Feb  1 11:02:06 <localhost> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 7548F12004F: removed
```

However I get the exact same return if I pass an entirely invalid email address (one which when tested from e.g. Outlook returns a non-delivery receipt).

Console output indicates the system is capable of DSN. Running the debug command `sendmail -bv <me@my_email_address>` returns the console message `Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <me>`, and the maillog has DSN entries:

```
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/pickup[16208]: 83BC11200A5: uid=<my_uid> from=<me>
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/cleanup[8341]: 83BC11200A5: message-id=<20170126083438.83BC11200A5@<localdomain>.localdomain>
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 83BC11200A5: from=<me@<localdomain>.localdomain>, size=316, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/smtp[8343]: 83BC11200A5: to=<me@my_email_address>, relay=<our ip address>[<our ip address>]:25, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.01/0.01/0.02, dsn=2.1.5, status=deliverable (250 2.1.5 Recipient OK)
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/cleanup[8341]: 8F0591200A7: message-id=<20170126083438.8F0591200A7@<localdomain>.localdomain>
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/bounce[8344]: 83BC11200A5: sender delivery status notification: 8F0591200A7
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 83BC11200A5: removed             
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 8F0591200A7: from=<>, size=1988, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/local[8345]: 8F0591200A7: to=<me@<localdomain>.localdomain>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jan 26 08:34:38 <localdomain> postfix/qmgr[2243]: 8F0591200A7: removed
```

So the system appears to be capable of DSN Delivery Status Notification which would appear a good way fwd but I need to help on how to implement this. This is a new area for me so explicit details would be great. Many thanks